Understanding ConvLSTM2D application with seasonal data
I have a dataset of the form (samples, t, x, y, channels), where x, y are pixels and t the sequence length. The data is seasonal, so each t represents a season. t doesn't extend far, as there's only one temporal label that was build over many years. My hope is to use ConvLSTM2D to capture seasonal effects on my features and connect those seasonal changes to the same label. This model would then be used with features from the following year  (and perhaps further) to predict the overall change of that year. As I understand it, it is a form of nowcasting, though what I want to predict are proportions (i.e. what classes make up an image).
I'm currently attributing my issue to my lack of understanding. When training, the metrics give me good results. The metrics I use are accuracy, modified f1 score for the majority class, rmse, and r2.
When evaluating on data with the same t, the metrics give me average results. It's quite a large drop, but still a somewhat usable model considering I haven't done much fine-tuning.
The model seems unusable for different t. Say for example, if I train on t=(1,8) inclusive (8 seasons) and evaluate on t=(9,12), I get very poor metrics. And it is a similar case even when the prediction is done on t=(1,4), half of the data used in training.
My expectation of ConvLSTM2D was that I could use a sequence of say 10 seasons to predict the 11th season. But the results I get indicate otherwise.
Any ideas?
